# Search and replace doesn't work with sed busybox. getting sed: unmatched '/' error

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, find-and-replace

I am trying to search a particular string and replace all occurrences within a file.

```
sed -i -e "s/$search_string/$replace_string/g" $filePath
```

I keep getting `sed: unmatched '/'`error on BusyBox v1.35.0.
However the same thing works fine on my local system.

And **No**, neither the  `$search_string` nor the `$replace_string` contains any `/`. I have tried using all types of delimeters too just in case.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659): some specific values of `$search_string`, `$replace_string` and `$filePath` for which the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because the $replace_string was a base64 encoded string with spaces and new line

```
replace_string=$(echo -n $json_string | base64)
```

changing this above command to

```
json_string=$(echo -n $json_string | base64 -w 0)
```

solved it for me

> -w, --wrap=COLS
> Wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76). Use 0 to disable line wrapping.